# Measures of accuracy for discrete variables

Tags: accuracy

I am testing the accuracy of discrete variable prediction (>= 2 possible outcomes). I've seen things like using a confusion matrix or ROC curve for binary outcomes, but not much for > 2 outcome variables.

What are good measures of accuracy for discrete variables other than classification accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

One of the accuracy measures i always use is kappa statistic and no information rate.

If you are using R programming, this is availabe in caret package and confusionMatrix() function.

Some of the other measures are true positive rate, false negative rate.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

One of the most important considerations is if you truly have discrete classification predictions. That you are analyzing the ROC curve for a binary outcome tells me that you do not have discrete predictions but something on a continuum like a predicted probability or log-odds (as would come from a logistic regression). Especially if there is a reasonable interpretation of the predictions as probability values (this is often but not always the case), this opens up a world of proper scoring rules that evaluate the predicted probabilities. Among the advantages of this is that it allows for more nuanced decision-making. Frank Harrell discusses these extensively in two great blog posts and all over his posts on Cross Validated.

[Damage Caused by Classification Accuracy and Other Discontinuous Improper Accuracy Scoring Rules](https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/)

[Classification vs. Prediction](https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/)

Among the common evaluation metrics for these kinds of predictions are the Brier score and log-loss. These can be normalized to Efron's and McFadden's pseudo $R^2$ scores to give possibly easier interpretations that are $1$ for perfect predictions and less than $1$ for imperfect predictions, analogous to $R^2$ in regression.

The equations in the multi-class setting are messy, but they work about how you would expect when you generalize from the binary to multi-class setting.